# After we run the data-migration tool in Magento 2, MSRP(click for price) will not work

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, magento2.1.5, magento2-migration-tool

This is an issue in default Magento 2 instance. To fix this issue, we have to apply product type for MSRP product attribute. we can only do this from MySQL query. please update the below query:

> update catalog_eav_attribute set apply_to =
>   'simple,configurable,bundle,grouped' where attribute_id = '120';

Please note that the attribute_id('120') is MSRP Product attribute.

Comment: I run this query, but still i can't see msrp in product edit page. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367948/display-actual-price-msrp-display-actual-price-type-product-attribute-and-rrp

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you guys should modify `mrsp`/`msrp_display_actual_price_type` with `simple,virtual,downloadable,bundle,configurable` as `apply to` value

Comment: I run those queries but still i can't see MSRP in product edit page https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367948/display-actual-price-msrp-display-actual-price-type-product-attribute-and-rrp