# Display Actual Price => msrp_display_actual_price_type product attribute and RRP => msrp not showing after magento1.9.2.1 to magento2.4.6 migration

Tags: magento2

Tow product attribute is not showing

1. Display Actual Price => msrp_display_actual_price_type
2. RRP => msrp
   not showing after magento1.9.2.1 to magento2.4.6 migration.
   [image]

[image]

[image]

the msrp_enabled was not migrated after migration, i added it manually from admin.

[image]